# Real approximation for homogeneous spaces of linear algebraic groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology, open-problems

Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically integral variety over $\mathbf{Q}$, having a $\mathbf{Q}$-point.
We say that $X$ has *the real approximation property* if $X(\mathbf{Q})$ is dense in $X(\mathbf{R})$.

Let now $X$ be a homogeneous space of a connected linear algebraic group $G$ defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.
Since $X$ has a $\mathbf{Q}$-point, we may write $X=G/H$, where $H$ is a $\mathbf{Q}$-subgroup of $G$,
not necessarily connected.

> **Question 1.** Does real approximation hold for any homogeneous space $X=G/H$ of any connected linear algebraic $\mathbf{Q}$-group $G$,
>   where $H$ is not necessarily connected?

Serre proved real approximation for  algebraic tori over $\mathbf{Q}$ (i.e. when $G$ is a torus and $H=1$).
Sansuc proved real approximation for connected linear algebraic groups over $\mathbf{Q}$
(i.e. when $G$ is any connected linear algebraic group over $\mathbf{Q}$ and $H=1$).
One can prove real approximation for homogeneous spaces with *connected stabilizer*
(i.e. when $G$ is a connected linear algebraic group over $\mathbf{Q}$, and $H\subset G$ is any connected $\mathbf{Q}$-subgroup).
In the general case (i.e. when $H$ is non-connected)  I expect the negative answer, but I cannot construct a counter-example.

The question can be stated in terms of Galois cohomology. Assume for simplicity that $G=\mathrm{SL}_n$,
then $H^1(\mathbf{Q},G)=1$ and $H^1(\mathbf{R},G)=1$.
Any orbit of $G(\mathbf{R})$ in $X(\mathbf{R})$ is open.
If such an orbit contains a $\mathbf{Q}$-point, then $\mathbf{Q}$-points contained in this orbit are dense in this orbit,
because our $G=\mathrm{SL}_n$ has real approximation.
We denote by $G(\mathbf{R})\backslash X(\mathbf{R})$ the set of orbits of $G(\mathbf{R})$ in $X(\mathbf{R})$.
Now our question is, whether the canonical map $G(\mathbf{Q})\backslash X(\mathbf{Q})\to G(\mathbf{R})\backslash X(\mathbf{R})$ is surjective.
There is a canonical bijection
$$
G(\mathbf{Q})\backslash X(\mathbf{Q})=\mathrm{ker}[H^1(\mathbf{Q},H)\to H^1(\mathbf{Q},G)]=H^1(\mathbf{Q},H)
$$
and similarly $G(\mathbf{R})\backslash X(\mathbf{R})=H^1(\mathbf{R},H)$,
so in this case Question 1 can be stated as follows:

> **Question 2.** Is it true that for any linear algebraic group $H$, defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ (not necessarily connected or abelian)
>   the localization map $\mathrm{loc}_\infty\colon H^1(\mathbf{Q},H)\to H^1(\mathbf{R},H)$ is surjective?

If the group $H$ is connected or abelian, then the localization map $\mathrm{loc}_\infty$ is surjective
(Sansuc's  proof in the case of finite abelian $H$ uses the Chebotarev density theorem
and the fact that a decomposition group of $\infty$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$, hence cyclic).
In the general case I expect the negative answer,
i.e. that there exists a *finite* non-abelian algebraic group $H$
 over $\mathbf{Q}$ for which the localization map
$\mathrm{loc}_\infty$ is *not surjective*, but I cannot construct such a counter-example.

Comment: Could you stop by http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87665/a-question-on-algebraic-torus and leave a reference for the Serre result? Thanks!